# Interceptor not called on weblogic

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, cdi

Currently I'm evaluating Weblogic 12c, but the interceptor is not called by weblogic. The Code is put into a library in the lib folder of an ear. The interceptor is binded with @Extern to an EJB in an ejb module. I enabled it in the beans.xml. The code runs with Glassfish 3.1.2 and Jboss 7.1.1. I tried to find bugreports for weblogic but I didn't find anything the correctly describes the problem. I wonder why this didn't result in a bugreport, so I simply want to know if there is a failure, 'cause I can't imageine that such a thing is a not known bug ...

```
@Interceptor
@BindOuterScope
public class OuterScopeInterceptor
{

    @Inherited
    @InterceptorBinding
    @Target({TYPE})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface BindOuterScope
    {

    }

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object invoker(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception
    {

    }
}

@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@BindOuterScope
public @interface Extern
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Earlier Glassfish had an issue where interceptors weren't always enabled. Could be something similar. Try redeploying a few times and see if something works. I know that sounds bad, but there isn't a better way of telling :(

Comment: I didn't expect to find the solution to my own problem in this thread, but you saved my life, Sir ;) I have a smiliar interceptor and annotation in a Tomcat application, but the interceptor would never be called, though correctly implemented and defined in `beans.xml`. I cleaned the Tomcat work directory from within Eclipse and now everything works fine.

Answer (score -1):

If you use the Eclipse WebLogic plug-in, you can make it work by changing the publishing mode to "exploded archive".

> - Right clic on the server > properties > WebLogic > Publishing
> - Check the "Publish as an exploded archive" > OK
> - Republish your application